# $L^{1}$ and $L^{\infty}$ norms are not equivalent on compact sets

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

Let $B \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be compact and $C(B)$ be the vector space of continuous functions $f: B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Prove that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|f\|_{L^{1}} &:=\int_{B}|f(x)| d x \\
\|f\|_{L^{\infty}} &:=\sup \{|f(x)|: x \in B\}
\end{aligned}
$$
are two norms on $C(A)$ which are not equivalent.

First, can I say that f is a continuous function on a compact set and thus Riemann integrable? and that Riemann integral will be equal to Lebesgue integral?
I thought to take an example for 1D but not sure that it's enough to show that these norms are not equivalent

Comment: If you intend to prove that the norms are not equivalent for arbitrary $B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, it is sufficient to demonstrate a counterexample for any $B$.

Comment: How about proving for a concrete $B$, like a cube.  Now you have to show that there exist $f$ on $B$ with $\|f\|_{\infty} = 1$, but $\int_{B} |f| $ small. Perhaps even do it in the case $n=1$.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting. I thought maybe in 1d to take:$f_{n}(x)= \begin{cases}1-n x & \text { if } 0 \leq x \leq 1 / n \\ 0 & \text { if } 1 / n<x \leq 1\end{cases}$

Comment: But first, I am not sure I can use Riemann integrability to show that there are norms in Lebesgue meaning of integration..

Comment: You have to assume that $B$ has non empty measure (or $||f||_{L_1}$ will always be zero, that does not make for a good norm). Even more, if you want it to be zero only for the zero function, you have to assume that in the neighborhood of any $x \in B$, close enough to $x$, either $B$ still has positive measure or the only point in $B$ in the neighborhood is $x$

Comment: hint: try $f(x):=x^{-1/2}$ in $(0,1]$ and $f(0)=0$ in the compact set $[0,1]$

Comment: If $B$ was an interval like $[0,1]$, could you find continuous functions that approximate the function $x \in ]0,1] \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$? If we do things correctly, we may expect the functions to have a bounded integral yet an unbounded maximum (like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$)

Answer (score 3):

In this case
$$\|f\|_{L^{1}}\leq \|f\|_{L^{\infty}} |B|$$
where $|B|$ denotes the volume of the compact set $B$.

Now, to show the norms are not equivalent we have to show that the inequality
$$\|f\|_{L^{\infty}}\leq C \|f\|_{L^{1}} \qquad (1) $$
is not true for any constant $C$ independent of $f$.

Simply consider the functions $f_{n}(x)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{n}}}$
on the compact set $B=[0,1]$.
Then $\|f_n\|_{\infty}=\sqrt{n}$. But $\|f_n\|_{L^1} \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Notice that $\|f_n\|_{L^1}=2(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})=2\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.  More imprtantly, we have shown that $$\|f_n\|_{L^{\infty}}/\|f_n\|_{L^{1}}>n.$$ Therefore (1) is not true with a constant $C$ independent of $f$.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to come up with a proof on your own by drawing pictures.

Note $\|f\|_1$ is the area under the graph of $|f|$, and $\|f\|_{\infty}$ is the max height of the graph of $|f|$.

If the two norms are equivalent, then there are constants $c,C>0$ such that $$c\|f\|_{1} \leq \|f\|_{\infty} \leq C \|f\|_{1}$$
for all $f$ in $C(B)$. You want to prove this does not happen.

Take $B = [0,1]$.

Draw the graph of a non-negative continuous function whose area underneath is 1 and whose max height is 10. Now graph of a non-negative continuous function whose area underneath is 1 and whose max height is 100. Finally, draw the graph of a non-negative continuous function whose area underneath is 1 and whose max height is 1,000,000.

Using what you learned from drawing graphs, show the following: For arbitrary $C > 0$, there exists a non-negative continuous function $f$  such that $\|f\|_{\infty} > C\|f\|_1$. That's the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea $f_k(x) = 1-k x$ for $0\le x \le \frac{1}{k}$, and $0$ on $[\frac{1}{k}, 1]$ works OK for the set $B=[0,1]$. Indeed, we have $\|f_k\|_1 = \frac{1}{2k}$, and $\|f_k\|_{\infty} = 1$.  Now, to consider the case $B= [0,1]^n$, you can take $F_k(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = f_k(x_1)$, and again $\|F_k\|_{1} = \frac{1}{2k}$, $\|F_k\|_{\infty} = 1$. Now you can do a similar thing for every cube.